# Числовая последовательность

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки, оптимизация, числовые-последовательности

Изначально дана строка «0», далее на каждой итерации вместо исходной строки создаются новая последовательность, длиной в 2 раза больше предыдущей, которая состоит из перевёрнутой предыдущей последовательности и последовательности равной по длине предыдущей, но в которой каждый элемент на 1 больше, соединенные в одну строку. При этом величина всех элементов берётся по модулю 10, т.е элемент 1 меняется на 2, элемент 3 на 4, элемент 9 на 0.

Программа получает на вход два целых числа, записанных в разных строках. В первой строке записано число итераций k (1 ⩽ k ⩽ 31).
Во второй строке записан номер элемента i (1 ⩽ i ⩽ 2^(k−1))

Пример:
Ввод:
4
6
Вывод:
1
(Сама строка на четвёртой итерации: 21012123)

Я сделал несложный алгоритм, есть ли у вас идеи, как его можно оптимизировать по времени и памяти(если возможно)?

```
string = "0"
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
for i in range(n-1):
    a = []
    for i in string:
      if int(i) > 8:
        a.append((int(i)+1)%10)
      else:
        a.append(int(i)+1)
    str_tp = ''.join(map(str, a))
    string = string[::-1] + str_tp
print(string[k-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Задача решается рекурсивно, решение выкладывать не стану, но алгоритм достаточно простой.

Для того, чтобы узнать конкретную цифру, не нужно вычислять строку целиком:
каждая цифра новой строки зависит ровно от одной цифры в предыдущей.
[image: Диаграмма]

т.е. для того, чтобы найти цифру для `k=4` и `i=6`, сначала нужно найти цифру для `k=3` и `i=2` и прибавить к ней единицу по модулю 10, а для той цифры нужно сначала найти предыдущую и т.д.

Длина строки на каждом шаге равна 2<sup>k-1</sup>, а значит легко определить, в которой половине строки находится искомая цифра. Зная это можно выяснить, от какой именно цифры прошлой итерации "произошла" искомая, и какому изменению подверглась.

Comment: Да, логика правильная. Кстати, `2**(k-1)/2 = 2**(k-2)`. и сравнение скорее всего нужно не строгое `>=`, потому, что `i` отсчитывается от единицы. А если цифра в первой половине - ничего не прибавляем, но берем цифры в другом порядке. В общем запутаться несложно, так что при тестировании сравнивайте результат со своей нынешней функцией, она рабочая, хоть и не оптимальная.

Comment: Спасибо. Я во всем разобрался, но оказывается, что старый алгоритм работал неправильно(в основном для больших последовательностей). Почему это могло произойти? Может из за того, что в строках есть пустые символы или что при соединении строк что-то пошло не так.

Comment: @StranGGer99 возможно проблема есть, но я ее не вижу, кроме экспоненциального роста потребления памяти конечно. для `k=31` потребуется несколько (возможно десятков) гигабайт памяти.